# Building a tree in a web app using Python

Tags: python, treeview, web

I'm new to Python and web development (although I have development experience with Client/Server apps .. a little rusty), and I need to build a Python web application that populates an interactive tree from a database (for my PG degree).

I've tried PyQT4 which contains a QTreeView/QTreeWidget but couldn't run this form as a web application. I've used QT Designer to build such form but couldn't make it run as a web app.

From Google search (over two weeks) I know that Django is the best framework to build a web app for Python, but it doesn't have an interactive tree viewer (am I right?).

I'm very confused at the moment and don't actually know where to go from here.

I'd appreciate your help in answering the following critical questions:

1. Can Django help in building such application? i.e. Does it support web tree view?
2. Can I use QTreeView from PyQt with Django? or even can I build a web application directly using PyQT and QT Designer?
3. If neither are suitable; Your suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a python or django issue: presentation on the web is done using (X)HTML, other types of XML (such as SVG), and javascript to automate the client side.

Go ahead and use django for your project, but understand that to do this, you will need to also get the hang of (at least) a javascript library for this task.

Comment: Thanks Sheena and Marcin, I'll have to consider Django and Javascript (completely new to me), hope fully I can find some samples for Django that shows how to build such a tree. I can presume that you are not recommending the PyQt for this task, right?

Comment: I have no recommendation to make about PyQt. Note that your django component for such a task will likely be very simple - it just has to make the data available to the javascript layer, and serve up the page.

Answer (score 0):

google django treeview for a few implementations. Alternativly use JavaScript. Django and Javascript play nicely and there are loads of JavaScript Treeview implementations.

Comment: can you pls suggest one javascript treeview with editable feature for leaves(end value)